# Reading .xlsx file and write into database whith php

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, xlsx

I want to use PHPExcel in my project to read xlsx file from one server and write the data in another server's DB(phpmyadmin). I don't know a lot about php and I need someone to help me please.also I dont know how to connect to that server :(
my code in here it has some errors:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");


        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
  mysql_select_db("osweh", $con);

  require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
  $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Book1.xlsx");
  $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

  $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
  $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); 

  $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 

  $rows = array();
  for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
      $rows[$col] = mysql_real_escape_string($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue());

     }

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO xlsx ('f1','f2','f3','f4') VALUES ($rows[1],$rows[2],$row[3],$row[4]);");
    echo mysql_error;
  }

     mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: what are the errors..?

Comment: First error, column names in SQL statements (your `f1`, `f2`, etc) should be in backticks (`), not in quotes (')

Comment: Second error, if you're setting string values in an SQL statement, then they need to be quoted.... the fact that you're escaping the values suggests that you know they are strings

Comment: it doesn't insert into db,I change the quotes but in doesn't work. and can you explain how to correct the escaping method I have?(I have string in DB as you say)

Comment: Some excel files could contain blank lines at the end. Add an if statement to check if the first cell of the row is empty before try to insert it. Also consider to create the full insert string and then make the query to the db, it will be much more optimized (INSERT INTO xlsx (f1,f2,f3,f4) VALUES (x,x,x,x),(y,y,y,y),(z,z,z,z)....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO xlsx ('f1','f2','f3','f4') VALUES ($rows[1],$rows[2],$row[3],$row[4]);");
echo mysql_error;
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO xlsx ('f1','f2','f3','f4') VALUES ($rows[1],$rows[2],$row[3],$row[4]);");
if ($result === false) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

it's help you to see errors when you insert data incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Alter the statement:

```
$result =   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xlsx` (`f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4`) " .
                        " VALUES ( '$rows[1]', '$rows[2]', '$row[3]', '$row[4]');");
if ($result === false) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```